# Possible regex backtracking issues?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regex and input:

http://regex101.com/r/cI3fG4

Basically, I want to match on the very last "yo" and keep everything in green (group(1)).

This works fine for small files/input.

However, if I run this from within java against a very large (100k) file, which there are no pattern matches (just a bunch of text - war&peace snippet) it can take 10+sec to return from trying to find a match.  I am assuming backtracking issues with the regex (specifically the (.*) group(1) match).

What can I do to prevent backtracking per the use case and speed up this regex to satisfy the above requirements?

-- Java Code --

```
    // Works fine for this small snippet but when run against 100k large input
    // as described above some serious perf issues start happening.  

    String text = "Hi\n\nyo keep this here\n\nKeep this here\n\nyo\nkey match line here cut me:\n\nAll of this here should be deleted";
    System.out.println(text);
    Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^(.*)((\\byo\\b.*?(cut me:).*))$",
            Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(text);
    if (m.find()) {
        text = m.group(1);
        System.out.println(text);
    }
```

Comment: maybe using [Possessive Quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^([\s\S]*)\byo\b[\s\S]*?(cut me:)
```

Without `m` and `s` flags.

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/lC9yZ5

In my testing this is turning out to be faster than your regex. (**You can also check it on regex101's debugger**)

Comment: Also try `^(.+)\byo\b.*?(cut me:)` with `s` flag.

Comment: Both of these worked beautifully! Thanks so much! You are a true regex guru! =)

Comment: i have one last twist for you if you would plz. i can post a new post...but essentially how can I match the first legit "yo...cut me:" pattern?  http://regex101.com/r/rY5xD2  what I want is to match the very first legit "yo cut me:" pattern?  is this possible?

Comment: just posted a new ask: http://bit.ly/1g5K0FY per the above.  if you have aec appreciate your assist. thx

Comment: very much appreciate your time!